# Conver Html Text to Map in Java

Tags: java, html, mule

I have a scenario, where I have to read html string and create map object out of it.
Sample html is here.

[image]

Expected map object is 
[FirstName:Mohammad, LastName:Rafiq].

How can this be achieved in Java?

Thanks and Regards
Rafiq.

Comment: you need to use xml parses for extract part

Answer (score 2):

You could of course use something like Jerry, to query for the content you want and add it to a map. Kind of like jquery for java...

see: http://jodd.org/doc/jerry/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Aye, parse the html and add the pairs to your map that might look like:

`HashMap<string,string> mymap = new HashMap<string,string>();`

Adding pair:

`mymap.put("firstname",thefirstname);
mymap.put("lastname",thelastname);`

Comment: I don't think this is an answer on what Mohammad Rafiq asked? He probably wants to know how to get the data out of the HTML to put it in a map, not how you can put it in a map.

Comment: Ah, okay. I don't have any experience of html- or xml-parsers, and the only thing I would suggest would be to look for existing such parsers before writing your own.